# Why not all menus are available in context settings page?

Tags: routes, 7

I want to put main-menu to certain block via context.

But only few menus are available:

[image]

I've 3 contexts already, but none of them uses any menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context module, blocks in the *Blocks* reaction are grouped by the module that creates them. In this case, it is the **System** module that provides the **Main Menu** that you're looking for.